# Server A cant connect to Severs B's mysql database

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, ubuntu-12.04

I have two servers both running mysql on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have an application on Server A which has to connect to Server B's database.

I have opened the my.conf file on server B and make the following edit:

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Is there anything else I need to do? I still cant seem to connect.

Interestingly, I cant connect to Server B's database using the standard settings in my sql client software (Sequel Pro). I can however, connect to server B's database using Sequel Pro when using the SSH options.

Are there some security settings I need to disable?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe port 3306 is blocked on firewall on server B

To enable remote login to mysql three things must be done:

Port 3306 opened of firewall

mysql have to bind to at least one interfaces that is available from outside not only localhost

and you mysql user can connect from other than location (user@%)

Comment: Great answer.  The user I was using didnt have the correct permissions to connect from another host. Adding a % in the host field (within phpMyAdmin) fixed the issue